# Accessing members of a passed struct array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a method `levenshtein` that populates a 2D array of `struct`s w/ info and returns a pointer to that array. When I send it to another method, I get a `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)` error at runtime. Please help me w/ this hopefully obvious error.

```
struct chartEntry
{
    int num;
    bool left,
         up,
         diag;
};

struct chartEntry** levenshtein(char *s1, char *s2, bool toPrint)
{
    unsigned int s1Len,
                 s2Len,
                 i, //rows, general purpose index
                 j; //columns, general purpose index
    s1Len = strlen(s1);
    s2Len = strlen(s2);

    /***********************************
    Create and populate traceback chart
    ***********************************/
    struct chartEntry chart [s1Len+1][s2Len+1];

    //
    // code to populate chart here
    //

    //prints expected number
    printf("chart[3][3].num is %d", chart[3][3].num);
    return chart;
}

void testFunction(char*s1,char*s2)
{
    // both of these give segmentation faults
    printf("[3][3].num is %d", levenshtein(s1,s2,false)[3][3].num);

    struct chartEntry ** tmp = levenshtein(s1,s2,false);
    printf("[3][3].num is %d", tmp[3][3].num);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's 2 problems here.  Firstly, `chart` is an array of arrays. This cannot be converted to a pointer-to-a-pointer. Arrays and pointers are different. Your line `return chart;` must give you a compilation error which you should not ignore.

Secondly, even if it could be converted, `chart`'s memory is local to the `levenshtein` function and will no longer exist when that function returns. So you would be returning a wild pointer.

You have two options:

- allocate memory for `chart` using `malloc` and return a pointer to that (either one large block, or with two levels of indirection)
- have the caller allocate the array and the `levenshtein` function just writes values into it.

If you use the first option then you should not use the `printf` as you have done the first time in `testFunction`, because the memory would not be freed. You have to save the returned pointer, printf it, and then execute a sequence of `free` that is the reverse of the `malloc` sequence you used to allocate it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're trying to return a pointer to an array that's declared inside the function:

```
struct chartEntry** levenshtein(char *s1, char *s2, bool toPrint)
{
    // ...

    struct chartEntry chart [s1Len+1][s2Len+1];

    // ...

    return chart;
}
```

However, as soon as the program exits this function, this array falls out of scope and is destroyed, leaving you with a pointer pointing to invalid memory. This leads to *undefined behavior*: Maybe it works, maybe it doesn't, maybe it puts your computer on fire. Okay, that last one is pretty unlikely, but the point is, *anything can happen*.

There are two ways to deal with this problem:

- Create a static array *before* calling the function, and then pass a pointer to this array in the function call.
- Dynamically allocate memory in the function, which can then be returned as a normal pointer. (The calling function has to make sure the memory is freed after use, though, otherwise this may lead to memory leaks, which is a bad, bad thing.)

Comment: "Maybe it works"... very unlikely as it is stack space which the following printf will probably override for its own local variables....